# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.VisualC.Utilities' creating/loading any C++ project in VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio

Trying to open/create C++ projects in VS 2019 (v16.9.6) gives me errors like this:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.VisualC.Utilities, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I still get it after updating to latest VS 2019, rebooting, cleaning up %APPDATA%\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio, and disabling all the extensions.

Actually I don't even get that much detail trying to create a simple empty or console C++ app, I get a messagebox with "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation".

Google gives me 0 hits for that exact Microsoft.VisualStudio.VisualC.Utilities error, some similar ones suggest it might be a problem with Lightweight solution load mode, but I think that's only an option in 2017?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using the "Repair" function in the Visual Studio Installer.